# Need help in understanding this switch code - Days of the months

Tags: java, switch-statement, leap-year

I am learning Java at the moment and I have some problems understanding the use of switch here. I would really appreciate it if someone could explain it simple to me. 
So here's the code:

```
 public class SwitchDemo2 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
int month=3; 
int year=2000;
int NumDays=0;
switch(month) {
case 1: case 3: case 5: case 7: case 8: case 10:
case 12: NumDays=31; break;
case 4: case 6: case 9: case 11: NumDays=30;
break;
case 2: if ( ( (year%4 == 0) && !(year%100==0) ) ||
(year%400==0))
    NumDays=29;
else NumDays=28;
break;
default: System.out.println("Invalid month.");
break;}
System.out.println("Number of Days= "+NumDays);
 }}
```

What I don't understand is the definiton after case 2. "year%4==0" - alright, that makes sense, that's a leap year,  but what about !(year%100==0) or (year%400==0) ? Why do we use that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year - It is part of the definition of leap year.

Comment: the mod 100 and 400 is part of the definition of leap years

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of leap year:

if year is divisible by 400 then is_leap_year
else if year is divisible by 100 then not_leap_year
else if year is divisible by 4 then is_leap_year
else not_leap_year